# Item and ability visit on the same person

Tags: werewolv.es

Do roles like stalkers and harlots see two separate visits if a player visits the same player with an item and their ability at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

**Stalkers and Harlots identify where people go, not what they do**

If a stalker follows a person that makes two visits to the same target, they would only see one target, and thus only receive report of that single target. Their target only went to a single house (that was not their own) that night.

Similarly, if a person visits themselves as one of the two targets, the stalker will only solely identify the third party as the visited target.

The harlot can identify a self-visit. But, like with the stalker, multiple visits by the same individual are not seen separately. The harlot only observes who visited a place, not how many times or how many observed individuals.

**A good reason for this: loops**

If this were not the case, in large games it may be possible to do strange things in the game by generating very large reports by (ab)using the fibonacci sequence.

If a pair of harlots starts observing a multi-using person, and then a series of stalkers starts observing eachother, you would get 2, then 2, then 4, then 6, 10, etc. multiples of the same player in the report with each additional stalker/harlot. That would quickly get very unwieldy. (And very confusing).

Comment: has this changed? you used to be able to "hide" visits by using multiple items and stalkers/harlots would see you visit the same person twice, was a good way to hide a shift.

Comment: If that's true, that would be a bit of a bug: the stalker's description is that they follow you around and find out who you visit. If you could mask one visit with another that'd make no sense. The harlot checks who visited someone, so should only see one of the two?

Comment: I haven't played since March/April so this may have changed, it used to be that each action (night action and items) was treated as a seperate visits. So with enough items a stalker could see you visit someone 2 or 3 times, same with harlot. So. You could have multiple visits to multiple players, and so if you shifted it wouldn't be blatantly obvious from the visits